# Not able to pass value from model to server

Tags: angularjs

Here I am fetching data from server using getprofile and displaying its value in appropriate text box.
then I am updating value using updatedata
Problem is that in server cl object{fname,lname,city} is not population with sent value.
my code is below

```js
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("getprofile")
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data.clientList);
                            $scope.clientList = response.data.clientList;
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            alert("Unable to fetch ");
                        });
                $scope.submitForm = function (cl) {
                    console.log(cl);
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: "updateddata",
                        params: {cl: cl}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log("updated successfully");
                        $scope.success = "Updated successfully";
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log("not updated");
                        $scope.error = "Unable to update";

                    });
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                        <div ng-repeat="cl in clientList">
                            <div id="error-messages"  ng-show="error">{{error}}</div>
                            <div id="success" ng-show="success">{{success}}</div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <label for=fname">First Name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
                                    <input type=text"  class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"
                                           ng-model="cl.fname" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="First Name required"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
                                    <input type=text"  class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"
                                           ng-model="cl.lname" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Last  Name required"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <label for="city">City</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
                                    <input type=text"  class="form-control" id="lname" name="city" placeholder="City"
                                           ng-model="cl.city" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Last  Name required"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <label for="submit" class="sr-only" >Update</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
                                    <input type="button"  class="form-control btn btn-success" id="update"
                                           ng-click="submitForm(cl)"
                                           name="Update" value="Update"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How to resolve the above problem.

Comment: did you use cl as the varibale name of the parameter recieveing at the API.?

Comment: Is this code you actual app code? You have to use service/provider, service recommended for api calls when you are using an angular App.

Comment: Yes cl is variable at server side to hold data cl is object of class client(id,fname,lname,city)

Comment: I think you need to send data as `data: cl,` instead of `params`

Comment: You should pass data like this: ` params:  cl` .  `c1` is object here. in this case `params: {cl: cl} ` you are passing object of objects. Hence it may not working.

Comment: I tried this. It is not working.

Comment: Any one can please provide any tutorial link or demo of working code